# What is the distribution on the speed of particles in a liquid? (analogous to the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution)

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, ideal-gas, liquid-state

I know, for gases, the distribution on the speed of particles is the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. What is the corresponding distribution for liquids (e.g. water)? You can assume that the liquid is still, with no big external forces e.g. swirling it around or making it flow. Just like how the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution doesn't account for if a wind is blowing.

My thought is that it would also be a chi-distribution with 3 degrees of freedom, just with different constants.

Comment: So basically what is the velocity distribution of Brownian motion?

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm not sure. I can believe air behaves like brownian motion. But I can image that liquid has a significant viscosity/drag term that might throw a wrench into things. Especially because e.g. water molecules have strong attractions to each other.